# Qt Quick Controls 2 - Changing properties on another page

Tags: javascript, qt, qtquickcontrols2

I have an app that has two pages.  The first page of the app is defined in it's own two files:  Page1.qml and Page1Form.ui.qml.  The second page of the app is also defined in it's own two files:  Page2.qml and Page2Form.ui.qml.  I'm having trouble understanding how to change the properties of an item that exists on one page in the app using a control from another page.

Let's say I wish to change the text of a Label on Page 1 when a button on Page 2 is pressed.  I've already created aliases for both the Label and the Button.  For the button's implementation in Page2.qml, I would expect to use the following code:

```
button.onClicked: {
        Page1Form.label_sourceValue.text = "Text has changed.";
}
```

However, when pressing the Button while the app is running, I get the error code "TypeError: Type error" with a reference to the line of code where I set the text.

I am new to Qt, so I'm probably just doing something really stupid here...but after 3+ hours of looking on the net for answers, I'm ready to say uncle.  Any help would be great.

Comment: `Page1Form` would be the "type", you need to set the property of the object instance of that type. Give it an `id` and use that.

Comment: After giving the Page1Form in Page1.qml an ID, I still cannot see the object (using its ID) in the Page2.qml file.  How do you call/control objects from other QML files?

Comment: most people don't bother using the Designer, as it creates so much extra leg work having to create aliases for everything on the form in order to expose it out

Comment: @Jed - you cannot access ids that are in another object tree branch, only in the current source and down the object tree if they are not shadowed. You can use a property to access from the outside `property Something something: someId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Qt Quick Item can have two `ids`:

- The `id` provided inside the .qml file for the item. This id is not used in this example, e.g. `page1thisIdNotUsed` and `page2thisIdNotUsed`.
- The `id` given to an `Item` by its `parent`. Example `page1` and `page2` in the example below.

This example highlights one reason why nobody I know uses the Qt Designer for QML. The `Page1.qml` file just seems to get in the way and create extra code. In order to access the contents of `page1` or `page2` from `main.qml` we would now have to create extra aliases in `Page1.qml` and `Page2.qml`.

Instead, most people prefer to move the contents of `Page1Form.ui.qml` into `Page1.qml`. Delete `Page1Form.ui.qml`, and learn to to QML by hand instead of through the Designer.

Good luck!

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {
            id: page1
        }

        Page2 {
            id: page2
        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("First")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Second")
        }
    }
}
```

### Page1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Page1Form {
    id: page1thisIdNotUsed
}
```

### Page1Form.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    property alias label_sourceValue: label

    Label {
        id: label
        x: 152
        y: 128
        text: qsTr("Label")
    }
}
```

### Page2.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Page2Form {
    id: page2thisIdNotUsed
    button.onClicked: {
        page1.label_sourceValue.text = "Text has changed.";
    }
}
```

### Page2Form.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Item {
    property alias button: button

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Press Me")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll keep in mind what you've said about not using the Designer.  For others looking at my original question, the summarized answer is to create an ID in  the main.qml under the appropriate object (in this case, Page 1) and then use that ID in the Page2.qml button.onClicked.